# Chrome DevTools freezes on large data uri

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools, data-uri

I am working on a project that uses image data uri's to preview images using the style `background-image: url(data:...)`

My issue is when using the DevTools it freezes for awhile on large backgrounds because of the amount of string data needed. I can get around this in development by using an external url for testing instead, but I would like to know if there is any way to get Chrome to stop trying to show all the data?

[image]

I know Chrome could solve this by just truncating the data for me, so maybe it is a bug, but I'd like to know if there is some setting or way to get around this.

Comment: Likely a chrome bug, after all, users are not expected to use the dev tools - so it'll be a no-problem when it's in production. I'd let it be.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue here. If you disable word wrap in the **Elements** section of the DevTools settings it helps. Might still give a lag but it should at least let you browse around.

[image: Elements settings in Chrome DevTools]

Comment: This doesn't fix the crash that happens when you try to view the details of an ajax request with large amounts of base64 data.